# How can I evaluate an equation of the first degree that contains parentheses?

Tags: python

I try to evaluate an equation with first order parentheses in order to get the result.

In this equation it contains certain numbers and a variable x.

```
fmts = (
  '-{}x - (-{} - x) = {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} + x) = {}',
  '-{}x - ({} + x) = {}',
  '-{}x + ({} + x) = {}',
  '{}x + ({} + x) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - (-x - {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - (-x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - (x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x + (x + {}) = {}',
  '{}x + (x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}',

)
```

In the previous tuple I manually create all the possible combinations of said equation.
With that I make sure that these equations can be obtained correctly.

I create the regular expressions with the random variables that will take a random number:

```
w,x,y,z = randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40)
expr = choice(fmts).format(w,x,y,z)
```

But I can't evaluate it because I don't know how to do it. I have tried sympy, but it has not worked for me.
I tried `print(f" {expr} = {eval (expr)} ")`, but it obviously doesn't work. Does anyone have any way to be able to evaluate these kinds of equations? Tahnks very much.

Comment: You could try [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: What exactly wasn't working with sympy?

Comment: @OlvinRoght That wouldn't work with values like `{}x` or `{}(x + {})`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I doubt that it should though, as patterns are initially defined in code, it shouldn't be a problem to add `*` between.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Sure, but then what is `x` supposed to be evaluated to? Seems OP wants to _solve for `x`_

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have no clue, probably there's a defined `x` variable in local scope. It's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Exactly, with sympy you can't evaluate `{} x or {} (x + {})`. What I want is to find the value of `x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
from random import randint, choice


fmts = {


  '-{}x - (-{} - x) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-{} - x) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-{} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x - ({} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x - ({} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x + ({} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x + ({} + x) - {}',
  '{}x + ({} + x) = {}' : '{}*x + ({} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + (x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + (x + {}) - {}',
  '{}x + (x + {}) = {}' : '{}*x + (x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} - x) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (-{} - x) + {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} + x) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (-{} + x) + {}',
  '-{}x - ({} + x) = -{}' : '-{}*x - ({} + x) + {}',
  '-{}x + ({} + x) = -{}' : '-{}*x + ({} + x) + {}',
  '{}x + ({} + x) = -{}' : '{}*x + ({} + x) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '{}*x + {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - (-x - {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (-x - {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - (-x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (-x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - (x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x + (x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x + (x + {}) + {}',
  '{}x + (x + {}) = -{}' : '{}*x + (x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '{}x + {} = {}x + {}' : '{}*x + {} - {}*x - {}',
  '{}x + {} = {}x - {}' : '{}*x + {} - {}*x + {}',
  '{}x + {} = -{}x - {}' : '{}*x + {} + {}*x + {}',
  '{}x - {} = -{}x - {}' : '{}*x - {} + {}*x + {}',
  '{}x - {} = {}x + {}' : '{}*x - {} - {}*x - {}',
  '-{}x - {} = {}x - {}' : '-{}*x - {} - {}*x + {}',
  '-{}x + {} = {}x - {}' : '-{}*x + {} - {}*x + {}',
  '-{}x + {} = {}x + {}' : '-{}*x + {} - {}*x - {}',
  '-{}x - {} = {}x + {}' : '-{}*x - {} - {}*x - {}',
  '-{}x - {} = -{}x + {}' : '-{}*x - {} + {}*x - {}',
  '-{}({}x + {}) + {}(-{}x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*({}*x + {}) + {}(-{}*x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-{} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x - ({} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x - ({} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x + ({} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x + ({} + x) - {}',
  '{}x + ({} + x) = {}' : '{}*x + ({} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + (x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + (x + {}) - {}',
  '{}x + (x + {}) = {}' : '{}*x + (x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}'

  }

a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z = randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40)

view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))
expr = expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z)
view_expr = view_expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z)

x = symbols('x')

eq1 = Eq(eval(expr,{"x":x}), 0)
sol = solve(expr)
try:
  print(view_expr)

  raw_expr = expr

  eq1 = Eq(eval(expr,{"x":x}), 0)
  sol = solve(expr)
  print(f"{sol[0]}")
except:
  print('No tiene solución\n\n')
```